# Yii2; code running in "else" block first, and then running code before "if" block?

Tags: php, if-statement, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm completely lost as to why this is happening, and it happens about 50% of the time.

I have a check to see if a user exists by email and last name, and if they do, run some code. If the user doesn't exist, then create the user, and then run some code.

I've done various testing with dummy data, and even if a user doesn't exist, it first creates them, but then runs the code in the "if" block.

Here's what I have.

```
if (User::existsByEmailAndLastName($params->email, $params->lastName)) {
    var_dump('user already exists');
} else {
    User::createNew($params);
    var_dump("Creating a new user...");
}
```

And here are the respective methods:

```
public static function existsByEmailAndLastName($email, $lastName) {
    return User::find()->where([
        'email' => $email,
    ])->andWhere([
        'last_name' => $lastName
    ])->one();
}


public static function createNew($params) {

    $user = new User;
    $user->first_name = $params->firstName;
    $user->last_name = $params->lastName;
    $user->email = $params->email;
    $user->address = $params->address;
    $user->address_2 = $params->address_2;
    $user->city = $params->city;
    $user->province = $params->province;
    $user->country = $params->country;
    $user->phone = $params->phone;
    $user->postal_code = $params->postal_code;

    return $user->insert();
}
```

I've tried flushing the cache. I've tried it with raw SQL queries using `Yii::$app->db->createCommand()`, but nothing seems to be working. I'm totally stumped.

Does anyone know why it would first create the user, and then do the check in the if statement?

Editing with controller code:

```
public function actionComplete() 
{

    if (Yii::$app->basket->isEmpty()) {
        return $this->redirect('basket', 302);
    }

    $guest = Yii::$app->request->get('guest');
    $params = new CompletePaymentForm;
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

    if ($this->userInfo || $guest) {

        if ($params->load($post) && $params->validate()) {

            if (!User::isEmailValid($params->email)) {
                throw new UserException('Please provide a valid email.');
            }

            if (!User::existsByEmailAndLastName($params->email, $params->lastName)) {
                User::createNew($params);
                echo "creating new user";
            } else {
                echo "user already exists";
            }

        }

        return $this->render('complete', [
            'model' => $completeDonationForm
        ]);

    }

    return $this->render('complete-login-or-guest');
}
```

**Here's the answer after multiple tries:**

Passing an 'ajaxParam' parameters with the ActiveForm widget to define the name of the GET parameter that will be sent if the request is an ajax request. I named my parameter "ajax".

Here's what the beginning of the ActiveForm looks like:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'complete-form',
    'ajaxParam' => 'ajax'
])
```

And then I added this check in my controller:

```
if (Yii::$app->request->get('ajax') || Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
    return false;
}
```

It was an ajax issue, so thanks a bunch to Yupik for pointing me towards it (accepting his answer since it lead me here).

Comment: Where this `if` is called?

Comment: @Yupik It's called inside a controller. I've noticed something very weird. It has to do with validating form input using Active form. Apparently if I run the `validate()` method, it runs the entire controller method (and suppresses any output, or does a weird redirect), and then loads the controller method again. I'm guessing this is why this error is happening. The first time it's running the controller method to validate inputs, and then creating a new user, it calls the method another time, but by then, the user has already been created... At least, this is what I think is happening.

Comment: show controller code

Comment: @InsaneSkull edited with controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `'enableAjaxValidation' => false` to your ActiveForm params in view. It happens because yii sends request to your action to validate this model, but it's not handled before your `if` statement.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. :( I even tried disabling client side validation, and still nada.

Comment: Try to check network in developer tools in browser. If it sends any - we have to dig deeper in ajax requests.

Comment: I edited with my controller code too if it helps at all.

Comment: So apparently setting `'enableClientScript' => false` fixes it... but now I've got no client side validation running.

Comment: Try deleting `enableClientScript` and set `validationUrl` to '/'. What happens then?

Comment: Doesn't work. I even tried wrapping my code in a `if (!Yii::$app->request->isAjax)` statement, but it doesn't seem like ajax is the issue. Looks like ajax validation is also off by default in the ActiveForm.

Comment: Last guess try: set `validateOnSubmit` to false in `ActiveForm`

Comment: I solved it by passing `'ajaxParam' => 'ajax'` in the ActiveForm, and then doing this check in the controller. `if (Yii::$app->request->get('ajax') || Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            return false;
        }` Looks like it works now. What a weird thing. Very bizarre thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can put validation like below in your model:

```
public function rules() { return [ [['email'], 'functionName'], [['lastname'], 'functionforlastName'], ];}
public function functionName($attribute, $params) {
   $usercheck=User::find()->where(['email' => $email])->one();

    if($usercheck)
    {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Email already exists!');
    }  
}
```

and create/apply same function for lastname.

put in form fields email and lastname => ['enableAjaxValidation' => true]

In Create function in controller

```
use yii\web\Response;
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
     Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON; 
     return ActiveForm::validate($model); 
} 
else if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
{ 
    //place your code here 
}
```